# Forge: Restart NodeJS daemon after deploy

Tags: php, node.js, laravel, vue.js, forge

I've setup my first Laravel Forge site that runs a VueJS 2.0 server side rendered app.

I've setup quick deploy and a daemon that keeps it running, but on deploys it doesn't restart. The same app is running which mean that only the new CSS is updated.
How can I make the daemon restart or should I do something else?

EDIT:
I'm using nginx

Comment: Are you using nginx or apache ?

Comment: I'm using Nginx

Comment: try restarting nginx. `sudo service nginx restart`

Comment: Would like it to do so on deploy. So I would just do it on the deploy script and then the daemon will catch up by it self?

Comment: You css files aren't updated, right? It can be because they are cached by NGINX therefore restarting NGINX will reload new CSS files

Comment: No. ONLY CSS is updated as the app is running the Vue instance which therefore isn't updated. On local I would just terminate the node.js process and restart it. So I guess that's kinda the same procedure I have to do now, but in the deploy script and/or daemon.

Comment: Ohh.. for restarting the server whenever a change is made to it. You can look at Nodemon or forever watch flag which will restart server when change is made.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the ID of the daemon in forge, and then add this to your deploy script

```
sudo supervisorctl restart daemon-YOURDAMEONID:daemon-YOURDAMEONID_00
```